# Setting up this environment with conda?

Tags: conda, environment

I'm trying to follow these instructions to create a conda environment with this [YAML file](https://github.com/CBIIT/NCI-DOE-Collab-Pilot2-Autoencoder_MD_Simulation_Data/blob/main/python_environment.yml) on an HPC but the environment keeps getting stuck on solving.

```
name: p2b1
dependencies:
- python=3.7.5
- scipy=1.5.3
- keras=2.4.3
- h5py=2.10.0
- numpy=1.19.5
- tensorflow-gpu=2.2.0
- pandas=1.2.0
- scikit-learn=0.24.0
- tqdm=4.56.0
- matplotlib=3.3.3
- numba=0.52.0
- astropy=4.2
- patsy=0.5.1
- statsmodels=0.12.1
```

It works when I only include numpy in the list of packages and add conda forge and defaults into the YAML file. Any way to resolve this?

(I am using conda version 23.3.1, but I have several working environments with this version I can't afford to lose so I'm concerned about updating it unnecessarily)

I tried installing just numpy with the YAML file and it worked.

Comment: How long do you leave it solving for? It really can take ages sometimes. Have you tried setting up the same environment on a desktop machine? Are you sure you need exactly those package versions? Python 3.7 is quite old, for a start.

Comment: Please only apply tags that actually make sense (read the tag description). You seem to have a file with ASCII characters in it, but you did not apply the tag `ascii` and rightfully so. There is no Python program here, and conda already implies Python. I assume there is some conflict in version numbers for the packages

Comment: Updating **base** `conda` should not impact other environments. If you are really concerned about updating to `conda >= 23.11` (the one that switches to the fast `libmamba` solver), instead use a standalone copy of Micromamba to create this environment. Best guess right now is your channel configuration doesn't match that used by the YAML author. The repo that provides this file should be alerted that *not providing channels* is a bad practice.